# jPicker change color transparent + get object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colors, get

I'm using [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/),I have 2 Questions.

1.How can I change the color to the transparent one? Already tried using

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.acive.val('hex','FFFFFF',this)
```

-> Found this , not sure if the best solution
    $.jPicker.List[0].color.acive.val('ahex','00000000',this)

2.Other is how can access without using the "index", like a selector.

For example something like:

```
$('selector').color.active.val('hex','FFFFFF',this) -> just an idea
```

Comment: you need to use 8digit values last 2 are the transparency `FFFFFF00`. but do you want to change the default RGB values without the alpha? because i think your solution is the best

Comment: Thanks , it seems to work... Now i need a answer for the second question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Chris Tillman, and I kinda (completely) wrote the plugin you're using. To accomplish the first question, just run

```
$.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('a', 0, this);
```

That will set just the alpha value for the active color.

If you want to get to the DOM element without using the List, just set it equal to a variable at instantiation like so.

```
var MyPicker = $('selector').jPicker()[0];
```

Just remember the index location at the end as the jPicker ALWAYS returns the result of $('selector').each(). If you are using one selector call for three different pickers, you can forget the index call at the end and get to each on using MyPicker[0], MyPicker[1], MyPicker[2] ...   The $.jPicker.List[] is a master collection list for ALL instances of the picker, where this solution will ONLY index the pickers created by that individual call.

Answer (score 0):

This method is a bit more complicated but you can check this answer to get the actuall ID

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27445752/2307326