# Jpicker transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jpicker jpicker-1.1.6.js from http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/

My code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
      {
        $.fn.jPicker.defaults.images.clientPath='/img';
               var LiveCallbackElement = $('#Live'),
        LiveCallbackButton = $('#LiveButton');
    $('#Binded').jPicker({window:{title:'Gama de Cores', position:{x:'screenCenter', y: 'bottom'}},color:{active:new $.jPicker.Color({ahex:'993300ff'})}});
    $('#LiveButton').click(
      function()
      {
        $.jPicker.List[7].color.active.val('hex', 'e2ddcf', this);
      });
    $('#GetActiveColor').click(
      function()
      {
        alert($.jPicker.List[8].color.active.val('ahex'));
      });
  });
</script>
```

And what I would like to know is, how to disable the transparency option from color picker selection box?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jPicker change color transparent + get object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360823/jpicker-change-color-transparent-get-object)

Answer (score 0):

```
.QuickColor:last-child {background-image: none;}

$('.QuickColor:last-child').click(function(event) {
    $('.QuickColor:last-child').unbind();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit noob in Jquery where exactly do I insert this code?