# jPicker set color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jpicker

I'm using jPicker plugin to get a color from a picker. 
I create the element in this way:

```
           $(function(){
                $('#txtBackgroundColor').jPicker(
                {
                    color:
                    {
                        mode: 'h', // acceptable values "h" (hue), "s" (saturation), "v" (brightness), "r" (red), "g" (green), "b" (blue), "a" (alpha)
                        active: new $.jPicker.Color({ hex: 'eaeaea' }), // accepts any declared jPicker.Color object or hex string WITH OR WITHOUT '#'
                    },
                    window:
                    {
                        position:
                        {
                            x: 'screenCenter', // acceptable values "left", "center", "right", "screenCenter", or relative px value
                            y: '200px', // acceptable values "top", "bottom", "center", or relative px value
                        },
                        expandable: true
                    },
                },

            });
```

When I click a button I want to set the active color of that jpicker. I have seen in the documentation this line:

```
$('#update').click(function(){
    $.jPicker.List[0].color.active.val('hex', 'e2ddcf', this); 
});
```

But the problem is that I have multiple jPicker, and I don't know the index of the List for example, is there a way to set the jPicker color by id and not by index List?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the value**

```
var control= $('#txtBackgroundColor')
var colorPicked = '#e2ddcf';
control.jPicker({
   color: { active: colorPicked}
});
control[0].color.active.val('hex', colorPicked);
control.val(colorPicked.replace("#", ""));
```

Dependent on your scenario some of the lines above may be irrelevant.

**Finding the ID** if:

```
$('#txtBackgroundColor')
```

is incorrect look for the span with jPicker class on it like this

```
<span class="jPicker">
```

Just above that, there should be an input with a display style of none with an ID value. Use that one in the above example.

Answer (score -1):

You're syntax wasn't right. Fixed it.

You could use .each() to target each element like this:

```
$(function() {
$('#txtBackgroundColor').each(function() {
    $(this).jPicker({
        color: {
            mode: 'h', // acceptable values "h" (hue), "s" (saturation), "v" (brightness), "r" (red), "g" (green), "b" (blue), "a" (alpha)
            active: new $.jPicker.Color({
                hex: 'eaeaea'
            }), // accepts any declared jPicker.Color object or hex string WITH OR WITHOUT '#'
        },
        window: {
            position: {
                x: 'screenCenter', // acceptable values "left", "center", "right", "screenCenter", or relative px value
                y: '200px', // acceptable values "top", "bottom", "center", or relative px value
            },
            expandable: true
        },
    })
});
```

});

Comment: No the code is right.. the code that you have updated is right works fine, I can have multiple picker with different id.. I want to set after initialized another color

Comment: Well, the question is clear: I initialize a jPicker with some value after I initalize other jPicker with other ID, if I click on a button I want to set a new color for a specific jPicker.. Jfiddle isn0t necessar, I nly want to know if is possible ot find a jPicker by Id and set its color clicked on a button